# Simulating multiple SVN users on a windows computer

Tags: windows, svn, version-control

How can I simulate multiple SVN users on a Windows computer for learning SVN?

I'm using the book [*Version Control by Example* by Eric Sink](http://ericsink.com/vcbe/vcbe_a4_lo.pdf), and want to be able to do all the stuff from page 17 to 20 from one computer, preferably Windows (though I do have Linux as well if need be).

**EDIT** - I will be adding updating my follow up questions to this question in the comments right below the question. I hope that this will prepare other readers to setup everything correctly to use this book.

My 2 cents.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975987/cannot-connect-to-local-svn-server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035602/resolving-a-merge-conflict-when-i-do-svn-update

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole thing sounds overly complicated. Here's an easy way to do it:

1. Use `svnadmin create` to create a repository.
2. Go into the repo's `conf` folder. You'll see a `passwd` and a `svnserve.conf` file.
3. In the `svnserve.conf` file. Look for the line `# password-db = passwd` and remove the `#` in front. This was line #27 in my repo.
4. Open the `passwd` file, and create multiple logins. They show you two examples, *sally* and *harry*. The format is `<user> = <password>`.
5. Save the file, and go to the parent directory of your repository.
6. Run the `svnserve -r <repoName>` command. Don't close this Window. Instead open another console window to run the other commands below.
7. Go into another directory, and do a checkout using the `svn://` protocol. Add the `--username` and `--password` parameter when you do a checkout. This will checkout the repo to the user whom you named.
8. Go into yet another directory and do another checkout using the `svn://` protocol with the `--username` and `--password` pointing to yet another user.

Each working directory will be default for those two users. The important thing is not to use `file:///` as a protocol. Use `svn://`:

```
C:> svn co --username harry --password harrysecret svn://localhost
```

By default, the commit will be of the user who did the checkout. The first checkout you do will be the root of the repo. You should add in the `trunk`, `branches`, and `tags` directory to simulate an actual Subversion repository structure.

The `file:///` protocol is used for basic testing if you don't want to run a server. It should never be used by multiple users, and you should never run a real repository with it. (The main thing it's used for are for web-based repository browsers like [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org because `file:///` is very fast.) There's really little need for `file:///` because `svnserve` is fairly easy to get up and running. And, you can even make it a [Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16281946/368630).

---

### Following the Exercises in the Book

> I added a bounty. Here is the book - ericsink.com/vcbe/vcbe_a4_lo.pdf. I want to be able to do all the stuff from page 17 to 20 from one computer, preferably windows. I have linux as well if need be

The book makes some assumptions about the computer you're using (Looks like a Mac), and is a bit confusing as it switches from Harry to Sally and back. We'll simplify this by using one Console window when you are *Sally* and one when you are *Harry*.

You need to get a good Windows text editor. ***Do not use Notepad!!***. Notepad is not a programming editor. Get [Notepad++](http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org). It's GUI oriented, and simple, but powerful. It's also open source and free.

Below I list the differences between the directions in the book and what you'd do on your Windows box. I'm assuming you have Administrator access on your Windows box.

### Page 15

Creating the Repository on a Windows computer. We'll create the repo under C:\repos\lottery>:

```
C:\> mkdir repos
C:\> cd repos
C:\repos> svnadmin create lottery
C:\repos> cd lottery\conf
C:\repos\lottery\conf> notepad++ svnserver.conf
```

You will find the line that sets where you are setting the password database. It's line #27 in my repository. You'll see the `#`. Remove this from the line. The `#` comments out the line. You want the line to read `password-db = passwd`. Then save the file. This tells the Subversion server process that the file `passwd` will contain the users and passwords for your repository.

Now edit the `passwd` file with `notepad++`. You want it to look like this:

```
### This file is an example password file for svnserve.
### Its format is similar to that of svnserve.conf. As shown in the
### example below it contains one section labelled [users].
### The name and password for each user follow, one account per line.

[users]
harry = harryssecret
sally = sallyssecret
```

All I did was remove the comment sign (`#`) from the two example users. Save the `passwd` file. Your repository has two users that are allowed to commit and make changes. Sally's password is *sallysecret* and Harry's password is *harrysecret*.

You currently are in the directory `C:\repos\lottery\conf`. Let's fire up the repo:

```
C:\repos\lottery\conf> cd C:\>
C:\> svnserve -d --root=repos
```

### Page 16:

On the same machine, go make a directory called `C:\workdirs`. This is where we'll make Harry's and Sally's working directories. Open another Console Window for this. This Console Window will be for Harry's work:

```
C:\> cd \
C:\> mkdir workdirs
C:\> cd workdirs
C:\workdirs> mkdir harry
```

Now, do Harry's Checkout:

```
C:\workdirs> cd harry
C:\workdirs\harry> svn co --username harry --password harrysecret svn://localhost/lottery
```

You may get asked if you want to store the passwords in your client configuration, and a warning that they'll be stored in plaintext. Go ahead and say `yes` to those questions. This way, you don't have to keep entering in the password each time.

Now go into Harry's working directory

```
C:\workdirs\harry> cd lottery
```

You're now in Harry's working directory.

Don't touch the `.svn` directory! This stores the information on your working copy: Who checked it out. What repository. What version, etc.

You should be able to do everything until you get down to Chapter 3 on the bottom of Page 17:

Now, create Sally's working directory:

Open ***another*** Console window. You now have three console windows open:

1. This is the `svnserve` process that's running. Closing this window will shut down `svnserve`. You can minimize this.
2. This is Harry's working copy.
3. This will be Sally's working copy.

It's easier to keep everything in separate Console windows. In fact, you can change the window color scheme to help you quickly recognize which window you're in. Create Sally's working copy:

```
C:\> cd \workdirs
C:\workdirs> mkdir sally
C:\workddirs> cd sally

C:\workdirs\sally> svn co --username sally svn://localhost/lottery
password: •••••••
```

Because you didn't use the `--password` parameter, you're asked for Sally's password. Again, if you're asked about storing the passwords, go ahead and say *yes* for now. This way, you don't have to keep typing in Sally's password.

Finally:

C:\workdirs\sally> cd lottery

This is Sally's working directory.

You should be fine using Sally's Window to Page 19 when we switch back to Harry's working copy.

From now on, if you are working with Harry's working copy, simply switch to Harry's window. If you are working as Sally, switch to Sally's window. Everything else should be fine, and just follow the examples all the way through.

Comment: OK, but "1. Install VisualSVN Server 2. Add 2 users in GUI" will be shorter way :-)

Comment: @LazyBadger - Thats what I did before I got this answer. I had no clue what to do after that.

Comment: @DavidW - What does this code `password-db = passwd` do ? I'll be running steps soon and giving feedback.

Comment: That tells `svnserve` (after all, it's the `svnserve.conf` file!) that the password database is in a file called `passwd`. Removing the `#` in front makes the line active. Then you add the users in `passwd`. You can use a different working directory (checkout) for each user.

Comment: @DavidW. - The svnserve command needs to be changed to `svnserve -d -r <repoName>`. Otherwise, you get the error - You must specify exactly one of -d, -i, -t, --service or -X. Type 'svnserve --help' for usage.

Comment: @DavidW. - Step 7 "Go into another directory". Which directory ? Would any random directory do ? "This will checkout the repo to the user whom you named." Where is the directory for this repo ?

Comment: Create two directories called harry and sally somewhere,say in the parent directory of your svn repo. Then, do the checkouts for each user into their respective directories.

Comment: @Steam Are each user a separate project? Multiple users can use the same _repo_.

Comment: @DavidW. - I don't understand what this means - each user a separate project. This is what the book author does first `~ harry$ svn checkout svn://server.futilisoft.com/lottery` for harry. Then, he does some commiting and after that `~ sally$ svn checkout svn://server.futilisoft.com/lottery`. So, I thought I should make separate folders for each user where he can keep his copy of the repo.

Comment: @Steam About the `svnserve` command. Try it with `svnserve -d -r <dir>`. That's what I use Unix/Linux/Mac. However, Windows doesn't have the concept of `daemons`, and since you're not making this a service, I figure you wouldn't want any options. Try the `-d`, but I bet the `svnserve` still runs in the foreground, so don't close the console window. Or try it with `-X` instead of `-d` which is the debug mode.

Comment: @Steam Don't create separate folders in the repo. The whole purpose of version control is to let multiple people edit the same files and project in an organized way. Both will checkout the same URL. However, each user should have their own folders for their checkout.

Comment: @DavidW. - I did not create in repo. I made two user folders in folder above repo folder. Now, people can checkout their code to their own folders - harry and sally respectively. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidW. - I am now having problems. The author does this - `~ harry$ svn checkout svn://server.futilisoft.com/lottery` and `~ harry$ cd lottery`. When I do the second command, i get an error - `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: @DavidW. - I added a bounty. Here is the book - http://ericsink.com/vcbe/vcbe_a4_lo.pdf. I want to be able to do all the stuff from page 17 to 20 from one computer, preferably windows. I have linux as well if need be.

Comment: @Steam See **Following the Book Exercises** addendum on my answer. These are changes to the book's directions.

Comment: On a Windows box, you can run as a service by using the SRVANY.EXE (see https://support.microsoft.com/KB/137890).  I have had success with this method in the past.

Comment: @DavidW. - One last question. In page17, harry makes some C code and checks it into the repo. Which folder do I put the C code in and where do I put the compiled code ? Do both need to be checked into repo, or only the C code. Thank you very much. You saved me !!!

Comment: PS - I did not enable the passwords. For anyone learning this, note that the SVN client and svn server versions should be the same, otherwise, when you checkout into harry, you get the error given here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259360/subversion-svn-e160043-expected-fs-format-between-1-and-4 . NOTE that I did this on windows 7 64 bit. I will try to get a commandline based C-compiler for windows or use gcc of MinGW. Lets see where this goes.

Comment: Don't check compiled code into Subversion or any version control system. It takes up a lot of room in the repository and isn't necessary. You have the source, and you can create the compiled code from that.

Comment: NOTE - Put a user's code inside his lottery folder. Then do the check in.

Comment: @DavidW. - Sorry ! One last question - Would it help to create that trunk, branch etc. folder structure ? Thanks!

Comment: You usually have that trunk, tags, branches somewhere in your repo. Either at the root of the repo, or the root of all projects in your repo. In this lesson, it wasn't done.

Comment: @DavidW. - When I run the command on page 18 - lottery harry$ svn commit -m "initial implementation", I get the error in the below comment. Could this be because I did not set passwords for harry and sally ?

Comment: `c:\workdirs\harry\lottery>svn commit -m "initial implementation"
Authentication realm: <svn://localhost:3690> some-code-here
Password for 'steam': ****
Authentication realm: <svn://localhost:3690> some-code-here
Username: steam
Password for 'steam': ****
Authentication realm: <svn://localhost:3690> some-code-here
Username: harry
Password for 'harry':
svn: E170001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E170001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://localhost/lottery'
svn: E170001: Authentication error from server: Username not found`

Comment: It could be. The `svnserve.conf` has two important configurations in it: Do you want anonymous read/write or read access? (default is read-only), and what file you're using for authentication (if you're using one). I told you to set it up for harry and sally with passwords. BTW, who is steam and why are you being asked about steam's password?

Comment: @DavidW. - Steam is the name of a windows 7 user account, for me.

Comment: Subversion and Windows are using two different sets of accounts. You can setup a "steam" account in the `passwd` file, but it will use the password set in the `passwd` file. You can setup Subversion using LDAP that can connect to your Windows Active Directory server, but that's a bit tricker to do, and not when you're learning SVN.

Comment: It now WORKS !!! Steps - Install visual svn server. Create repo and users in the same locations, but only using the visual svn interface and not commands. Then, create the workdirs folder with its two users and follow the answer. This was my svn server `https://localhost/svn/lottery/`. Now, check out and commit using this server and the commands given in David's answer.  Related post -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975987/cannot-connect-to-local-svn-server.

Comment: @DavidW. - David, I have one new problem in this book. Can you please help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035602/resolving-a-merge-conflict-when-i-do-svn-update

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simulate multiple users working on the same project, then you can setup a Subversion + Apache HTTP Server package (VisualSVN Server, SVN Edge) and then use multiple working copies under different users to "work" on the project.

I don't actually see any practical or learning value in your instruction.

Comment: "different *windows-users*" is single weak point. Can be avoided

Comment: @LazyBadger I regret that I don't fully understand the comment T__T

Comment: If you use sifferent SVN-users under the same Windows users - without additional tricks SVN will remember auth details for first SVN-user (`# store-auth-creds = no` by default in config) and use it later in ech and every WC of this Win-user. Single repo, single Win-iser, many SVN-users means *uncommented* `store-auth-creds = no`

Comment: @bahrep - How do I simulate the same svn commandline codes with the visual svn server gui ?

Comment: @bahrep - My progress so far - Created two users harry and sally. Created a lottery repo which is accessible to all users. Now, how do I make harry checkout the blank repo ?