# SVN merge conflict editing: What do vertical bars ("|||||||") mean?

Tags: svn, merge-conflict-resolution

When I hand-edit a merge conflict after `svn update`, I find something like this in the file:

```
<<<<<<< .mine
    act();
||||||| .r328
    bid();
=======
    cue();
>>>>>>> .r329
```

**What do the vertical bars ("`|||||||`") mean?**

Before posting this question, I checked the [section on merging conflicts by hand](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve.byhand) in the online book [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), `svn help merge`, and ≈20 guides to resolving merge conflicts with SVN (e.g.,
[1](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/wiki/TasksHelp/ResolvingConflicts),
[2](https://openoffice.apache.org/svn-basics.html),
[3](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~mjc/teaching/Animation/exercises/miscellaneous/Flex%20Builder%203/configuration/eclipse/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui_1.0.5/html/reference/mark-resolved.html),
[4](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/org.tigris.subclipse.doc/topics/mark-resolved.html),
[5](https://ericsink.com/vcbe/html/ch03s05.html), [6](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/local/sys/web/subversion/linux/resolvingconflicts.html), etc.).  Searching for [svn edit conflict vertical bars](https://www.google.com/search?q=svn+edit+merge+conflict+vertical+bars) (with or without quotes) and other terms returned nothing useful.  I also searched Stackoverflow directly (e.g., [1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=svn+update+hand-edit), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012810/svn-keeps-corrupting-files-with-mine-how-to-fix/2012825), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035602/resolving-a-merge-conflict-when-i-do-svn-update), etc.).

How can this be so hard to find‽‽‽

Comment: It looks like the output from `diff3 -m`. You are comparing three instances of the file, your changes, r328 and r329.

Comment: @RichardSmith: You're right!!!  ([diff3 manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_mono/diff.html))  How about posting as an answer?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`svn` is showing conflicts (differences) across three different versions of the same file:

- The edited version of the file in your working directory
- Revision 328 in the repository
- Revision 329 in the repository

It looks like `svn` uses `diff3` with the `--merge` option to display these differences. See [this document](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_mono/diff.html#Bypassing%20ed) for details.