# Add new repository in Subversive

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, subversive

As I know we can use Visual-SVN for server and Tortoise-SVN for client as practice.

However, What if we are going to use subversive? Can subversive be both server and client? And if we going to use subversive as server,

how do we allow users to connect with it in 24 hour basis?
open public IP and keep running the Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

**Subversive** is just a plugin for **Eclipse**. Server and Client are different things.
For the server you can use whatever server you like. It can be **Tortoise**, **VisualSVN** or even download and compile the [source](https://subversion.apache.org/download.cgi) by yourself. **Apache** does not provide binaries. If you don't want to build the packages by yourself, you can look for binary packages [here](https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html).

Once you decided which package to use, if you use Windows, which I'm assuming you are, you can [set the `svnserve` to run as a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16281946/3501205). Which means it can run in the background for 24/7.

The client does not have to be a part of the same package as the server. There is no problem in having **VisualSVN** as your server and to use **Subversive** as your client. The only thing you need to keep in mind is the [SVN Version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/141146/3501205). Preferably the server and the client should be the same version.