# AnkhSVN error on updating solution: Can't write to connection: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: visual-studio, ankhsvn, svnserve, tigris

When I update solution in visual studio, I have got this error:

```
SharpSvn.SvnSystemException: Can't write to connection: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, SvnException error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, svn_error_t* error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Update(ICollection`1 paths, SvnUpdateArgs args, SvnUpdateResult& result)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Update(String path, SvnUpdateArgs args, SvnUpdateResult& result)
   at Ankh.Commands.SolutionUpdateCommand.PerformUpdate(CommandEventArgs e, ProgressWorkerArgs wa, SvnRevision rev, Boolean allowUnversionedObstructions, Boolean updateExternals, Boolean setDepthInfinity, IEnumerable`1 groups, SvnUpdateResult& updateResult)
   at Ankh.Commands.SolutionUpdateCommand.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<OnExecute>b__0(Object sender, ProgressWorkerArgs a)
   at Ankh.ProgressRunnerService.ProgressRunner.Run(Object arg)
```

When I update each project in solution separately, I have not this error.
This error appear on Visual Studio 2019 and Ankhsvn version 1.0.12

Our source server is running by a program called: **Subversion 1.3** (subversion.tigris.org) and Windows service wrapper for SVNServe. We have it from many years ago and just works find until now. Other solutions on this server also donot update and have same error.
I thought, upgrading **Subversion 1.3** may be is the solution, but the link to download tigris subversion do not work:
http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/NewsItemView?newsItemID=1685

I can see many page related to Apache Subversion, it seems like that is superset the old Subversion 1.3 , like this:
https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.12

also it has said:

> to upgrade an existing server installation, just install the newest libraries and binaries on top of the older ones.

but it doesn`t offer any package directly but have links to 4 other sites. Which one will update our **Subversion 1.3** (subversion.tigris.org)? Should I install these package and go to the installed folder and copy and paste each file over our older files as above site suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally We fix this error by installing latest version of this software, which include in both:
-TortoiseSVN(also select **Command Line client tools** when insalling)
 -CollabNetSubversion-client
Packages.
then we should setting up a new Network service this way:
[How to setup "svnserve --service" to run on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281172/how-to-setup-svnserve-service-to-run-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

Ankhsvn is abondonware. It's not had a "daily update" since 2017. I suspect your problem is there, and you need to look for a supported tool to replace it.

Comment: We have used Tortoise to update the working copy, but still get same error on some of our companies` computers. we edit our question, please answer it again.

Comment: Try switching to git and using git-svn. Ankhsvn is abandonware for many reasons, mostly that Subversion has fallen out of favor for many reasons.